# Build Interactive Web map for offline/localhost visualisation

Tags: shapefile, web-mapping, cartography, vector-layer, localhost

I am part of a small research project where we are leading field experiments in a small watershed, on some remote location far away from our research institute.

I have a series of vector data, shapefiles actually, consisting of various points, lines, polygons, each one representing some specific entity on the field: either rain gage stations, drillings, boreholes, contours, roads, parcels, etc... Also, for those entities, I have some photos taken with a camera to illustrate the actual state of the entity.

I would like to build a series of maps. I want them to be interactive, so that people can choose thematic layer entities of interest and display them, measure distances, etc. Also, it would be good to run them locally on the browser, without the need to install some third party software.

I don't have a clear idea on the way to go. Can anyone help pointing me in the right direction ?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.

Answer (score 1):

Without 3rd party installation there is no chance as you need a service providing your data to the browser (which is simplified said just a viewer) or any other software as a browser is no GIS. That is being said when you need to input data.

When it is just for looking at maps it can be done via Openlayers/Leaflet export from Qgis (extension qgis2web). You can activate, query data there and measure. But no way to get data back.

If it really needs to be with a browser application and you need to be able to input data you can install some webservice locally (Geoserver for example as it brings its own inbuilt webserver without the need of an apache). But you need to built your webapplication (lots of work!!! and programming skills needed) that gets the data from the webservice for presentation and interaction.

Why not go with a GIS if it needs to be more than looking on a map? For example with Qgis as a free and open source you have no licencing trouble and you can create nice input forms with dropdowns, photos and have GPS support and stuff.